# no data showing in google analytic using phonegap android

Tags: android, cordova, google-analytics, tracking

have integrated google analytic plugin from [here](http://phonegap-plugins.com/plugins/appfeel/analytics-google). 
**No data is displaying in my google analytic account.**i am running app on my internet enabled android device.
Also installed google play services from android SDK manager,given project dependency for google-play-service project added libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar file in my lib folder of project.
here's code for index.js:

```
var app = {
      startTime: new Date().getTime(),
      initialize: function () {
        this.bindEvents();
      },
      bindEvents: function () {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
      },
      onDeviceReady: function () {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
        app.testAll();
        app.setCampaignUrl("http://www.appfeel.com?utm_campaign=com.analytics.google&utm_source=github&utm_content=setCampaignFromUrl&utm_medium=link");
        app.setInstallerId("13456")
      },
      receivedEvent: function (id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');


        analytics.startTrackerWithId('my track id');
        alert("Start Time");
        analytics.trackTiming("app", "start", new Date().getTime() - app.startTime);
      },
      setInstallerId: function (id) {
          alert('installer id :'+id)
        var options = {};
        options[analytics.OPTIONS.APP_INSTALLER_ID] = id;
        analytics.setAppParams(options);
      },
      setCampaignUrl: function (url) {
          alert('campaign :'+url)
        analytics.setCampaignFromUrl(url); //"");
      },
      testAll: function () {
          alert('test all')
        var options = {};
        options[analytics.OPTIONS.APP_INSTALLER_ID] = "org.acme.app";
        analytics.setAppParams(options);

        alert("Set Campaign url");
        analytics.setCampaignFromUrl("http://www.appfeel.com?utm_campaign=com.analytics.google&utm_source=github&utm_content=setCampaignFromUrl&utm_medium=link");

      }
    };
    app.initialize();
```

thanks

Comment: You have to whitelisten the campaing url.

Comment: this would be difficult if i've dynamic campaign url. plus besides from campaign it should display start time.

Comment: That is not a question that you should whitelisten, it is a question of you have to. Otherwise your app will not be able to call an external url.